# Removing broken switch from mains extraction fan for project - how to work out what the colored wires are

Tags: switches, mains, fan

I have a kitchen extractor fan that I need for a scale model of [Corsi-Rosenthal cube/box](https://encycla.com/Corsi-Rosenthal_Cube).  The switch no longer works. It used to have a couple of speeds and a lamp.  I'm looking to just wire it directly (no switch) up and control it at the mains switch/plug (UK, 230V)

[image] [image]

I can't work out what is what for the fan's black, red, blue and white wires. I'm assuming there are two sets of windings inside the fan to make the two speeds. Or was it three speeds. I can't work out if I can go into trial and error with a low amp fuse. I've a neon screwdriver, but there's nothing I can use it for here safety-wise, I don't think.

Comment: The switch labels are missing, but speed controls are DPDT and ON OFF are DPST for power closest to green most likely main fan or light

Comment: why don't you use a soldering iron to reflow all of the solder connections? ... several appear to be cracked

Comment: Check the lead to pad for micro-annular ring insulation (fatigue broken solder joint)

Comment: yup - dry joints/cracks was true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahee, a puzzle, my favorite!

Let's number the switches from the bottom to the top => #1, #2, #3, #4.

**1) Switch #1: Fan light on.**

The switch #1 was the Fan Light (?), that you've cut out the wires. It connects the Line (Brown) and the Hot (Blue) to the light.

**2) Switch #2 push, #3 pop, #4 pop: Line<->White, Neutral<->Blue, Red & Black are open. => low speed**

The switch #2 turns on the fan when pushed in. It connect the white wire to the Brown (Line) wire. Meantime, the neon lamp lights up as well.

**3) #2 push, #3 push, #4 pop: L<->White, N<->Red, Blue & Black are open => medium speed.**

**4) #2 push, #3 push/pop (no effect), #4 push: L<->White, Red & Blue are open, N<->Black => high speed.**

So, you may connect the N(Blue from the plug) and L(Brown) to these:

> 1. Low speed: L <-> White, N <-> Blue
> 2. Medium: L <-> White, N <-> Red
> 3. High : L <-> White, N <-> Black

Comment: I went with #3 and didn't die or blow the main trip - https://youtu.be/GxLYYqdC0bQ

Comment: @paul_h , Love it.  I need something like that, too, for my cat. :-)

Comment: did you mean to say cat?  Imma getting scary images of "Will It Blend?" videos.

Answer (score 2):

You can test across the black contacts for continuity.

I doubt the speed or lamp switches are bad.

If black are open, then bridge both.

But check the solder pad to lead are connected even if they look ok.
[image]

Comment: I was flexing the board in rubber gloves and it worked then didn't work. Dry joints joints as my pa would say. Am also slightly embarrassed that I could have worked it out myself - your scribbled additions showing the way, thanks.

Comment: yeah that's pretty common failure with vibration induced solder

Comment: My pa had a workshop fixing cathode ray TVs and home electronics in the 80's and the engineers would live test such things by prodding the boards in known places. With insulated implements I guess as some of the voltages were very high.

Comment: IN HDD and PCB testing , I used random vibration tables to find flaws in early SMT production of motherboards and pushed it back to the supplier, a sister plant in Singapore, so they could do the same and fix the solder process. Imagine an earthquake in NYC, that's what the board looked like , much more complex than a MOBO.

Comment: Fix the solder process for the subsequent production runs, rather than fix the broken items? The former being more Toyota (production system) and less Jaguar from the 1970/80's.